# How to run this function for a larger dataset(9 features)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, svm

I am new to python. In my code i was trying to implement Support Vector Machine from scratch. The code previously had 2 features and 2 class(1 and -1) with 6 instances (for each class) and it was working fine. 
I am trying to implement the same code for 9 features and 2 classes(1 and -1) with 6 instances(for each class) and it is giving me a Value Error and I can't seem to fix it.
I am using Python version 3.6.3
Thank you for your help.

```
  #This is my dictionary/dataset
  data_dict = {-1: np.array([[1, 7, 4, 1, 9, 1, 5, 6, 7],
                       [2, 8, 6, 0, 8, 6, 8, 5, 2],
                       [3, 8, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 8], ]),
         1: np.array([[5, 1, 8, 2, 6, 4, 0, 2, -3],
                      [6, -1, 5, -2, 6, -3, 0, 5, 3],
                      [7, 3, 0, 4, 10, -6, 9, 8, 2], ])}

  #Call to the function
  svm = Support_Vector_Machine()
  svm.fit(data=data_dict)

#Function fit
def fit(self, data):
    self.data = data
       #Some more code here
                    #w_t and b intialized here

                    for i in self.data:
                        for xi in self.data[i]:
                            yi = i
                            if not yi * (np.dot(w_t, xi) + b) >= 1:
                                found_option = False
                                # print(xi,':',yi*(np.dot(w_t,xi)+b))

                    if found_option:
                        opt_dict[np.linalg.norm(w_t)] = [w_t, b]
```

## Error Message:

in module

```
svm.fit(data=data_dict)
```

in fit

```
if not yi * (np.dot(w_t, xi) + b) >= 1: 
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (9,) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 9 (dim 0)
```

Comment: what is the shape of w_t ?

Comment: @mujjiga Thank you!!  Thant was the problem. n_t was an ndarray with 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You. 
I figured it out. The problem was with the size and shape of the array w_t.
w_t had 2 elements and i was trying to multiply it with a 9 element array.
I fixed it and now its working fine.